# Customising the application name in a vscode workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code

As directed by the [VSCode github repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose) - I have an simple ask.  Is it possible to set a human readable application name for a [VSCode Workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces)?

At the moment, my `.code-workspace` file looks like.

```json
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "name": "Some project",
            "path": "../some-project"
        }
    ]
}
```

Having a look through the Settings (File->Preferences->Settings) for the Workspace there is a plethora of settings.  Curiously there is an `appName` environment variable - but surely there should be a way of customising this.

The title bar looks like the following with `acme.app (Workspace)`:

[image: title bar]

Curiously the workspace filename is called `acme.app.code-workspace`.

Answer (score 2):

I spotted window.title in settings when having a look earlier.  You can customise it in the `code-workspace`.  I am not sure whether this would be the best way.  Would be nice if we could set an environment variable `workspaceName` or something and use that - if we needed to use elsewhere.

If you add the settings section - then add the `window.title` it will default the value to `${dirty}${activeEditorShort}${separator}${rootName}${separator}${appName}`.

```json
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "name": "Some project",
            "path": "../some-project"
        }
    ]
    "settings": {
        "window.title": "${dirty}${activeEditorShort}${separator}${rootName}${separator}${appName}"
    }
}
```

Here you can see the following:

`dirty` - displays an indicator of whether the current file has changed
`activeEditorShort` - the current file
`separator` - configured separator i.e. '-'
`rootName` - defaults to acme.app (Workspace)
`appName` - defaults to Visual Studio Code

So you could change the rootName to be the human-readable text:

```json
"window.title": "${dirty}${activeEditorShort}${separator}MY SUPER PROJECT${separator}${appName}"
```

Which gives us:

[image: configured title]